# google play games service same e-mail account returns difference id

Tags: android, google-play-games

i'm using google-play-games-service plug-in for unity 0.9.26.

```
namespace GooglePlayGames
{
public class PluginVersion
{
// older versions, used when upgrading to other versions
public const string VersionKeyCPP = "00911";
public const string VersionKeyU5 = "00915";
public const int VersionInt = 0x0926;
public const string VersionString = "0.9.27";
public const string VersionKey = "00927";

// used to check for the correct min version or play services.
public const int MinGmsCoreVersionCode = 8115000;

// used to get the right version of dependencies.
public const string PlayServicesVersionConstraint = "8.1+";
}
```

my server identify user with this id

```
Social.localUser.id  //(like 123456789012345678901) 21character
```

i saw this id is unique, but after release my app sometimes user send difference id(not null or empty, like g1234568901234567890 start 'g' same 21character)
so server can't find user data.

is this my fault or kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a change in the behavior of Play Game Services.  The details are explained in more detail here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html.  The quick summary is:

Players are prompted to sign-in once per account, rather than once per game
Players no longer need their account upgraded to Google+ to use Play Games services.

Once players have signed-in for the first time, they will no longer need to sign in to any future games; they will be automatically signed in.

As a result, there is less friction in playing the game (no consent screen is needed, and no Google+ account is needed.

Please use the "Email" link under Contact Us in the help section of the Google Play Developer console to get more information during your migration efforts.

Comment: The player id is the correct id to use - this is just a 1 time migration. Do you have a published game that has this data?  If so please reach out to the support team for instructions on how to maintain your data.  If it is a new game, then you can safely use the player id.